# How to change a Quartz CRON expression dynamically in Grails

Tags: grails, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I'm actually working in Grails 3.x and I need to use Quartz Cron expressions. I've implemented successfully regular cron expression and works correctly, but now what I need to do is User (from a GUI) change that cron expression for any other he/she wants.

This is my Job

```
 class ScheduleJob
{
   static triggers = 
   {
       cron name: 'myTrigger', cronExpression: "*/5 * * * * ?"
   }
   def execute()
   { 
       println "------ Every 5 seconds"
   }
}
```

I would appreciate so much if someone could help me to know how to do that, thanks for your time. :D

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of options.  One thing you can do is call `ScheduleJob.schedule(' your cron expression goes here ')`.

You could also go get the job manager bean from the application context and reconfigure job beans there.

Some of the info at http://www.tothenew.com/blog/removing-triggers-and-rescheduling-a-quartz-2-job-programatically/ might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, was very helpful. :)